Missing methods in LiveWire TestCase
Trying to write some tests for my Laravel Livewire components following the official Livewire documentation, but I'm hitting brick walls from the very beginning. I have a feeling the issue is not with my code, but want to have it confirmed by some people more familiar with Livewire.
So the documentation gives this method as an example:
/** @test */
function post_creation_page_contains_livewire_component()
{
    $this->get('/posts/create')->assertSeeLivewire('create-post');
}

So here is my method following the same model:
/** @test */
public function manage_permissions_contains_livewire_component(): void
{
    $this->actingAs(User::factory()->create());

    $response = $this->get('/permissions');

    $response->assertSeeLivewire('manage-permissions');
}

The issue I'm facing is that there is no existing assertSeeLivewire method in the response returned.
My test class extends the Tests\TestCase test class which then extends the Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase class, which seems to be the correct TestCase.
The returned response is an instance of Illuminate\Http\Response.
The error message received is: -> BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Http\Response::assertSeeLivewire does not exist.
Is that documentation outdated (https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/testing) or is it me doing something wrong here?

I am getting this, but did not used to. I wonder if I fetched a new Composer update that broke something. The tests that are failing are bundled with Laravel Breeze, so they should run perfectly; I have not modified them.

it's good to know that it's not just me. I had to give up on using that method, because couldn't find the issue happening to anyone else. For some reason get method does not return the right response object.

I made a discovery since posting; I did a php artisan vendor:publish --all and this created all sorts of things that looks like they should be committed to version control. One of them was a config/livewire.php file, which I would wager is the solution to the problem. It looks like one or two of these assets I did commit, but not all of them. I will try this over the next couple of days.

@domjanzsoo: Have you enabled WAL mode for sqlite by any chance?

I had exactly the same error with Laravel 11, running a fresh Laravel Breeze bootcamp app while using sqlite as the backend. Same for the Laravel Jetstream tutorial app. I spent hours on finding the root cause and the eventual fix, and would have expected better from the otherwise wonderful Laravel docs.
Root cause: Test suite is incompatible with sqlite's WAL mode
In my case, the root cause was that I had enabled WAL mode for sqlite in the meantime:
// config/database.php (excerpt)

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DB_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
            'busy_timeout' => null,
            // 'journal_mode' => null, // This was the default.
            'journal_mode' => 'WAL',   // <=== WAL enabled here!
            'synchronous' => null,     // You want to set this to 'NORMAL', btw.
        ],

Apparently, the currently included test suite is incompatible with sqlite's WAL mode. I noticed that running php artisan test would somehow corrupt the (default) sqlite database at database/database.sqlite. The end result was an empty database/database.sqlite file at the end of a test run. The test run causing the corruption would typically hang and have an ever-changing permutation of failing Feature tests (Unit tests were fine).
For what it's worth, I suspect that the reason why the database file ended up being of file size 0 after a test run is somehow related to use RefreshDatabase, which all feature tests under tests/Feature/ have. RefreshDatabase "resets your database after each of your tests so that data from a previous test does not interfere with subsequent tests." as per the Laravel 11 docs. But maybe RefreshDatabase itself is not the real culprit, though.
class AuthenticationTest extends TestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

    // ...

}

Fix: Use a separate sqlite database for testing, with WAL mode disabled
I configured Laravel to use a separate testing database:
// config/database.php (excerpt)

        /*
         * Use a separate database for testing.
         *
         * 1. This allows us to keep our "regular" database untouched, which
         *    improves our development experience.
         * 2. More importantly, we learned that Laravel's testing harness (at
         *    least the default one created by Laravel Breeze/Jetstream)
         *    fails when using SQLite with WAL mode enabled.
         */
        'sqlite-testing' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DB_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database-testing.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
            'busy_timeout' => null,
            // Laravel's testing harness is, as Laravel 11 in September 2024,
            // apparently incompatible with SQLite's WAL mode. The default
            // journal_mode, DELETE, is ok to use.
            'journal_mode' => null,
            'synchronous' => null,
        ],

I then added updated my .env.testing file with:
# In .env.testing
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite-testing

Alternatively, update phpunit.xml and add:
// phpunit.xml
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite-testing"/>

Now, running php artisan test worked.
Important: If you decided to modify .env.testing rather than phpunit.xml, make sure that you have the correct APP_ENV configured when running the test suite so that .env.testing is actually being evaluated! If needed, force the environment to be testing like so:
# If `php artisan test` complains about a missing database file,
# run this first.  Even if the file has a size of zero, as long as
# it is not missing altogether, Laravel is able to recreate the
# sqlite testing database "on top" of the empty file.
# (I was quite surprised when I discovered that this was needed.)
$ touch database/database-testing.sqlite

$ php artisan test --env=testing

